# Swift Properties that conforms to a protocl

Tags: swift, generics, properties, protocols

I have this protocol:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
     func doSomething
}
```

I would like to use this protocol to ensure some properties are conforming to it like:

```
class MyClass {
   var detailVC : UIViewController <TestProtocol>
}
```

like good old ObjC to ensure the detailVC conforms to TestProtocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protocol MyViewControllerProtocol {
    func protoFunc()
}

class MyClass {
    var prop: MyViewControllerProtocol?
}
```

It's as simple as that. But if you want a pre-defined class to conform to a protocol, you then need to make an extension (but then this applies to the class as a whole) or you subclass it.

So...

As an extension to the class as a whole:

```
extension UIViewController: MyProtocol {
    func protoFunc() {
        print("do whatever")
    }
}
```

In this case, when extended, you can just set the property as:

```
var myProperty: UIViewController?
```

As after being extended, it'll conform as required.

Or just subclass it with:

```
class MyConformingViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    override func protoFunc() {
        print("do whatever")
    }
}
```

In this case, you just set the property as:

```
var myProp: MyConformingViewController?
```

And that'll automatically confirm to `MyProtocol` due to the class being set to conform to it.

You can't force a predesignated class to conform to a protocol which wasn't already designated to conform to it in the first place.

e.g. UIViewController wasn't originally set to confirm to `MyOtherProtocol` for example

That would defeat the object of protocols in the first place. This is why you either extend it to conform, or subclass it to conform.

Comment: Yeah this will work. one quick question, the method in the extension , would it ever get called?

Comment: The more I think about this, if Swift had virtual functions like Java this will be done by inheritance easily :(

Answer (score 0):

So you can implement the method like following:

```
class detailVC : UIViewController, TestProtocol {
    func doSomething() {}
}
```

Comment: This how my conforming class will look like, but you did answer the question on how ot make the property only accept this type of object (UIViewController the conforms to my Protocol)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can't have a variable of one type and also declared as a protocol type.

What you can have is a variable that needs conform more than one protocol.

```
 class MyClass {
    var detailVC : TestProtocol
 }

 class MyClass {
    var detailVC : protocol<TestProtocol,SecondProtocol>
 }
```